# Why does my Netbeans project not run?

Tags: java, netbeans

I cant run my Netbeans project!

```
 public static void main(String args [])
```

appeared with an error I couldn't find or fix so I proceeded to copy the same statement from another project (I saw that the statement was actually the same).

When I try to run it now I get red words on the output and not the frames and dialogs I added.

Did I just ruin my project?

I'm actually new to this and this project is going to be the grade for my finals and I had a LOT already done!

Please help! How can I make it run again???

The error I get is in the Ouput and has something like:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultCloseOperation must be one of: Do_Nothing on Close, HIDE ON CLOSE, or DISPOSE ON CLOSE"

and then:

at javax.swing.JDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(menuprincipal.java:575)

and then I get about 20 more similar to those.

Comment: Have you tried hitting ```Ctrl + Z```? You didn't make a backup or commit this to a repository?

Comment: Could you please share more of your source code with us?

Comment: Ctrl+Z was the first thing I tried. And really not trying to sound stupid but this is the very first time I use Netbeans or any other application like this one so I had no idea a backup would be useful!

Comment: What is the error saying, and what do the red words say?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: (@cricket_007 *"Every Java project has the method declaration you have shown."* - 1) Actually, that is incorrect. A webapp typically doesn't.  A library typically doesn't. 2) This misses the point that a method declaration needs to be in the right place.)

Comment: (@StephenC - Yeah. Semantics. Most or  "every pure, self-contained, runnable Java project")

Answer (score 1):

***CALM DOWN!***

> appeared with an error I couldn't find or fix so I proceeded to copy the same statement from another project (I saw that the statement was actually the same).

Probably a bad idea ...but not a disaster.

You probably pasted the "statement" into the wrong context.  (Hint: `public static void main(String args [])` is NOT a statement.  It is a method declaration.  If you put it somewhere that a method declaration is not allowed, you are liable to get *a whole lot* of compilation errors.)

> but when I try to run it now I get red words on the output and not the frames and dialogs I added.

Those "red words" are telling you that you have a compilation error.  Compilation errors are >>normal<<.  You just have to fix them.  If you open up your IDE's error view you should be able to see the error messages.  (I'm not a Netbeans expert.  Maybe some other Answer will instruct you on how to do that ...)

> Did I just ruin my project?

Nope.  You just have to fix the compilation errors that your ill-advised edits have introduced.

> I'm actually new to this and this project is going to be the grade for my finals and I had a LOT already done! Please help!

Maybe this episode will help you understand the importance of:

- regularly (at least daily) backing up your files, so that if you trash something you can get an older copy from your backups, and
- learning and using a version control system.

> How can I make it run again???

Just fix the compilation errors.  (We can't help you with that unless you show us the code and the compilation errors.)

Comment: I guess the question should be reverted since I removed most of these quotes :)

Comment: Well... the red words say Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultCloseOperation must be one of: Do_Nothing on Close, HIDE ON CLOSE, or DISPOSE ON CLOSE" and then I get lines saying "at" and different things and the number of the lines of the coding they are pointing to

Comment: @cricket_007 - I think it should.  Taking the long view, I think it is possibly instructive to future readers to understand that they don't need to panic when they see a compilation error ...

Comment: @gutgut - Not enough context.  Put the full details >>into the question<<.  Show us the full stacktrace, and the code that it refers to.

Comment: @Stephen C Ill try to. The problem is Im practically NEW to programming and dont know the terms or things but Im going to try

Comment: Well the whole point of your course is to learn ... and we can't do that for you.